# No notification of success or failure while running tests using the teamcity switch

Tags: angular, jasmine, teamcity, karma-runner

I am currently trying to configure angular jasmine tests to run during deployment in teamcity. I have made the necessary change in my karma.conf.js for it to run tests on teamcity.Here is the config.

```
// ====================================================
// More Templates: https://www.ebenmonney.com/templates
// Email: support@ebenmonney.com
// ====================================================

// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-teamcity-reporter')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'teamcity'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    flags: [
      '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--no-sandbox'
    ],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

However when i run the following command locally the out put is as per screenshot below. I am not sure of success or failure. Could somebody tell if there is any issue or its the way it is. I dont see ng build prod run either

ng t --reporters=teamcity --browsers=ChromeHeadless && ng build --prod

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration and CLI command looks OK to begin with, but seems like you can try tweaking them a little bit, or shedding a few of them too, and see what it outputs.

A few things you can try:

`singleRun: true`
`autoWatch: false`

I don't have sufficient knowledge about `flags`, but I think they should be set for the `browser` property? The following should work.

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessCI'],
customLaunchers: {
  ChromeHeadlessCI: {
    base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
  }
}
```

Another good practice would be to leave `karma.conf.js` as is and create a copy of it, like `karma-ci.conf.js`, that you can run like `ng test --karma-config=src/karma-ci.conf.js ...`. This way, you have a clean config file with just the necessary properties for the CI run. You can then remove all the unnecessary reporters from the config JSON, like karma-jasmine-html-reporter, istanbul, etc.

I wrote my experience on setting up Unit Testing in TeamCity in [this article](https://link.medium.com/PzEM418uC0)... if it helps.